# The probability that a continuous random variable equals a certain value is 0: Does that apply to finding even/odd values??

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I understand that the probability for any X to equal a certain value is 0 (X is a continuous random variable with a given probability density function (pdf)). **However, does that apply to finding the probability that X is even, or that X is odd?** For example, the way I see it, it would be like P(X is odd) = P(X = 1 or 3 etc. from the interval a to b). Which means that the probability here is 0 by the rule above. Am I looking at this wrong? Should I be looking at it as the total number of odd x's by using 'and', not 'or', however that still would not be a range to find an integral? (x is an integer on the graph). I am working with a uniform distribution.

To clarify, I want to find P(X is odd) on my range of values, and X is a continuous random variable with a pdf.

Comment: You are quoting a fact about  continuous variables and applying it to discrete random variables.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you elaborate? What part makes my problem discrete?

Comment: If $X$ is a continous random variable, then the probability that $X$ takes on an integer value is $0$. A fortiori, the probability that $X$ takes on an *odd* integer value is $0$.

Comment: It seems more like a problem of cardinality. Pdf is usually defined on a set with the cardinality of continuum, i.e. $c$. But collecting distinct points, however many, only results in "countable" sets.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, so I see what you mean by discrete, X taking on a specific value like an odd/even number. My X is still a continuous rv, so that means that P(X is odd/even) must still be 0 by the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous random variable have zero probability on all points.

So $P(x\text{ is even}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(x=2k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 0=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!